# Batch rename files in Linux

Tags: linux, rename, batch-rename

How I can rename images with 'rename' command from "something_full.jpg" to "something_500.jpg" recursive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you can use the `rename` tool for that. It should come in a Perl-based version with Debian-based Linux distros, but you can easily [download it](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=perl/perl.git;a=blob_plain;f=debian/rename;hb=HEAD) from source as well (obviously, you need to make it executable first with `chmod +x`).

---

The following command will replace the `_full` part with `_500` on all JPG files in the current directory.

```
rename 's/_full/_500/' *.jpg
```

To do this recursively, starting from your current directory, use `rename` with `find`.

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec rename 's/_full/_500/' {} \;
```

**Note:** You may want to test the command before actually executing is. In order to do that, add the `-n` option to `rename` (e.g. between `rename` and the `'s//'` string).

Comment: my bad, I underestimated Larry there! How about piping the jpg file paths instead of the `exec`?

Comment: Thank you. I successfully used `find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec rename 's/_full/_500/' {} \;`.

Comment: @nik Why would you trade the security offered by `find` against something that involves piping constructs (and may fail due to spaces in filenames, etc.)? I have found the latter to be insecure and hard to read at best.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [zmv](http://grml.org/zsh/zsh-lovers.html#_zmv_examples_require_autoload_zmv). zmv is a zsh specific feature, and requires `autoload -U zmv` to be somewhere in your `.zshrc` file.

EDIT: As an example, the task the OP posed could be solved with

```
noglob zmv '(*)_full.(*)' '$1_500.$2'
```

An excerpt from the `zshcontrib` man page:

> `zmv [ -finqQsvwW ] [ -C | -L | -M | -p program ] [ -o optstring ] srcpat dest`
>
> Move (usually, rename) files matching the pattern srcpat to corresponding files having names of the form given by dest, where srcpat contains parentheses surrounding patterns which will be replaced in turn by $1, $2, ... in dest.  For example,
>
> `zmv '(*).lis' '$1.txt'`
>
> renames `foo.lis` to `foo.txt`, `my.old.stuff.lis` to `my.old.stuff.txt`, and so on.
>
> The pattern is always treated as an EXTENDED_GLOB pattern.  Any file whose name is not changed by the substitution is simply ignored.  Any error (a substitution resulted in an empty string, two substitutions gave the same result, the destination was an existing regular file and -f was not given) causes the entire function to abort without doing anything.

EXTENDED_GLOB patterns are tremendously powerful. [Here](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/37/ZSH-Gem-2-Extended-globbing-and-expansion/) is a good primer on the concept.

Comment: I've added an example and some documentation.