# Rename all files in a linux directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch rename files in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/412450/batch-rename-files-in-linux)

I have a list of 1000 files in a directory in my linux system like this:

```
01-Star_Network.en.srt  
02-Subsets.en.srt  
03-Function_Comparision.en.srt
```

I want .en eliminated from all files, and rename them to:

```
01-Star_Network.srt  
02-Subsets.srt  
03-Function_Comparision.srt
```

Is there any bash, python, java or PHP script to do this?

Comment: It should be easy with any one of the tools you mention. The question is... what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this command :

```
rename 's/\.en\.srt$/.srt/' *.srt
```

`rename` is `Perl` `rename`, it's the default on `Ubuntu` :

```
$ LANG=C update-alternatives --display rename
rename - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/bin/prename
/usr/bin/prename - priority 60
  slave rename.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/prename.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/bin/prename'.
```

It's installed with `perl` `Ubuntu` package itself.

Comment: This will remove the first instance of ".en.": "01-.en.wikipedia.org.en.srt" will become "01-.wikipedia.org.en.srt". If you want to remove only the final "en", you could do `'s/\.en\.srt$/.srt/'`.

Comment: post editec accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The following command will do that:

```
find . -name '*.en.srt' | sed 'h; s/.en.srt$/.srt/; H; x; s/\n/ /' | xargs -l mv
```

- find finds the files to be renamed
- sed edits the filename
- xargs calls the mv command for each filename to do the job

To check first what you are doing, try adding 'echo' just before mv, like this:

```
find . -name '*.en.srt' | sed 'h; s/.en.srt$/.srt/; H; x; s/\n/ /' | xargs -l echo mv
```

Answer (score 0):

`rename` from `util-linux` should do that too:

```
rename .en.srt .srt *.en.srt
```